# Use defined variable in array

Tags: node.js

Confusing but hopefully someone knows how to do this

I have this code:

```
const abc = [];
const value = "bar";
const setting = "foo";
abc.setting = value;
console.log(abc);
```

I want it to output [ foo: 'bar' ] but it outputs [ setting: 'bar' ]

Comment: [ setting: 'bar' ] is an invalid type. do you mean { setting: 'bar' }?

Comment: I mean in an array, that's how arrays are laid out ( [ ] )

Comment: `const abc = {}; abc[setting] = value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[]` to indicate the dynamic keys for object.

```js
const abc = [];
const newObj = {};
const value = "bar";
const setting = "foo";
newObj[setting] = value;
abc.push(newObj);
console.log(abc);
```